# Unable to Install Phalcon

Tags: php, mamp, phalcon

While Installing Phalcon for PHP7, I am getting error:

```
Cannot find build files at '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/lib/php/build'. Please check your PHP installation.
```

I am using MAMP.

Comment: Have you checked that your PHP7 files actually exist in that location?